# Is it worth to use present perfect in this situation?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, present-perfect

I'm Russian and English is not my first language.

I'd like to say:

> we went to France every year

or

> we have gone to France every year

We did it in the past but now we don't. 
Which of the these sentences is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple past merely describes a past situation. So there's nothing complicated in the first sentence. You went to France every year in the past.

The present perfect connects a past situation to the present in some way. In this case, the connection with the present is the potential for occurrence, or recurrence, of the situation at any time within the time-span up to now. So the second sentence implies that there's a possibility that you'll be going to France this year.